# Rails Restful Authentication : Can't find UserObserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I am moderately new to Rails so this may be a stupid question...

I followed the basic steps noted on the [github site for the plugin](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master) (mainly installed the plugin, ran the generator, modified environment.rb and created the UserObserver class in the models directory)

The error I'm getting is saying it's coming from active_support/dependencies. **"'load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant UserObserver (NameError)."** Any idea on why it could not find the user observer class?

Comment: can you tell which plugin you installed?

Comment: Whoops I completely forgot to put the site link in. Sorry about that -- the standard restful_authentication at http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means it's looking for a constant called "UserObserver" (which generally means it's a class / module). It can't find it because you may not have a file called user_observer.rb, generally located in app/models or app/observers.

Answer (score 3):

Did you include both of these lines in your `environment.rb` file? Assuming `user_observer.rb` is located in `app/observers`.

```
config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/observers )%
config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the solution to your particular problem but you could take a look at [Bort](http://github.com/fudgestudios/bort/tree/master), which is a skeleton app that already has restful auth setup, and see what they have done that you haven't.

Comment: Bort looks pretty cool I think I will do that next time around.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem before.  Here's the solution:

Don't make any changes to the environment and routes files before using the generator. use the generator first; THEN add the...

map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'
 map.login  '/login',  :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
 map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'

...etc.

that should do it.